# Jquery click function with for loop

Tags: jquery

I will try to re explain the situation: I have a paragraph there are 72 words, and they have a toggleClass and these words are highlighted for the user and have a cursor. When any word is clicked I want to check the check mark according to that. So there is 72 check marks each has one.

```
    //adding to 72 paragraph words a toggle class
    $(".question_text span").click(function() {
        $( this ).toggleClass( "green" );
    });

    //gives id to every 72 words in the paragrapgh
    $('.question_text span').each(function(idx) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'a' + idx);
    });

    // checkmarks have id #Q15v2_1 to #Q15v2_72
```

So i want when the first word of the highlighted ones clicked to check check marik #Q15v2_1 when the second one is clicked #Q15v2_2 and so on, but when the word is uncliked the check-mark becomes unchecked

Comment: Can you provide the code you wrote please ?

Comment: sounds like you should be using a label which does it with no JavaScript needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop thru all elements the add a toggle like this:

```
$(.question_text span).each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(e){
        if($(e.target).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        } else if($(e.target).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        }
    })
})
```

This is only a example, but I think it is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('.question_text span').each(function(idx) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'a' + idx);
});

$(document).on('click', '[id*="Q15v2_"]', function() {
  $(this).prop('checked', !$(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

**For the explanation:**

I use event delegation: `$(document).on('click', '[id*="Q15v2_"]'` in case of you add dynamically your element. The selector `[id*="Q15v2_"]` select all element whose `id` contains `Q15v2_`

And this line `$(this).prop('checked', !$(this).prop("checked"));` toggle the property `checked` of the element you just clicked

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a different approach than others. Render the `[i]` with the correct values.

```
<label for="Q15v2_[i]">text</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="Q15v2_[i]" name="Q15v2_[i]">
```

That is what label are for, [no need for jquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif)

Comment: I do not have control over HTML